# Error: Cannot read property "name" of undefined. However, after the page is refreshed, the error is removed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, use-state

I have the following code for when the profile route is being called:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Row, Col, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import { getUserDetails } from '../actions/userActions'

const ProfileScreen = ({ location, history }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('')

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const userDetails = useSelector((state) => state.userDetails)
  const { loading, user, error } = userDetails

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin)
  const { userInfo } = userLogin

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userInfo) {
      history.push('/login')
    } else {
      if (!user.name) {
        dispatch(getUserDetails('profile'))
      } else {
        setName(user.name)
        setEmail(user.email)
      }
    }
  }, [history, userInfo, dispatch, user])

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // DISPATCH PROFILE UPDATE
  }

  return (
    <Row>
      <Col md={3}>
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>

        {error && <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>}
        {loading && <Loader />}
        <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <Form.Group controlId='name'>
            <Form.Label>Full Name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type='name'
              placeholder='Enter your Full Name'
              value={name}
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            ></Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group controlId='email'>
            <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type='email'
              placeholder='Enter your email address'
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            ></Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group controlId='password' className='my-3'>
            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type='password'
              placeholder='Enter your password'
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            ></Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group controlId='confirmPassword' className='my-3'>
            <Form.Label>Confirm Password</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type='password'
              placeholder='Confirm your password'
              value={confirmPassword}
              onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
            ></Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>

          <Button type='submit' variant='primary' className='my-4'>
            Update
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </Col>
      <Col md={9}>
        <h2>My Orders</h2>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  )
}

export default ProfileScreen
```

After the code is being executed, and the user goes to the profile route, at first it shows "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
however after the page is being refreshed, the error gets removed and the app then works completely fine.
[This is the error being shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu71m.jpg)

Comment: user.name value are undefined that why errors show first check in console value are coming or not

Comment: yeah at first the value is not coming, but on refreshing the page the value is coming in the user.name. So i don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: the below answer is working fine or not

Comment: the below answer is working but then the form doesn't autofill

Answer (score 0):

Please check your condition.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!userInfo) {
      history.push('/login')
    } else {
      if (Object.keys(user).length === 0) {
        dispatch(getUserDetails('profile'))
      } else {
        setName(user.name)
        setEmail(user.email)
      }
    }
  }, [history, userInfo, dispatch, user])
```

Comment: I tried your code, but then it won't autofill the form since the initial value of user is {} which is false by default, thus the else part does not get executed

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check your object is empty or not **Object.keys(user).length === 0**

Comment: it's working fine now. Actually the reducer function was being exported properly but vsCode wasn't reading it as a const